# VBA Get HTML Element Info for Changing Id

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to create an excel web scraper that logs into my companies ticket tracking system and logs certain information on the sheet (Lead assigned, Desired Date for the project, etc.). I was doing fine until I had to pull a field off the website that has a changing ID.

For example, on two pages the same field will have the IDs:

- "cq_widget_CqFilteringSelect_32"
- "cq_widget_CqFilteringSelect_9"

Can somebody provide guidance to how I should search and paste the "IT Lead" value into excel?

[HTML snippet of div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFo5H.png)

[Snippet of actual website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNco2.png)

[Setup in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/382km.png)

Below is what I have so far

I get confused in this area:

> lead = objCollection(i).Value

```
Sub CQscrub()

Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim objCollection2 As Object
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim numbers() As String
Dim size As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim objLead As Object
Dim objLead2 As Object
Dim lead As String
Dim counter As Integer

size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1)) - 4
ReDim numbers(size)

For row = 10 To (size + 10)
    numbers(row - 10) = Cells(row, 1).Value
    'Cells(row, 2) = numbers(row - 10)
Next row


Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Height = 1000
ie.Width = 1000
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://clearquest/cqweb/"

Application.StatusBar = "Loading http://clearquest/cqweb"

Do While ie.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Application.StatusBar = "Searching form. Please wait..."
'Had these below as comment
Dim WRnumber1 As String
WRnumber1 = Range("A10").Value
'Range("A6").Value = WRnumber1


Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).row 'last row of A

'Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input") originally here
For counter = 0 To size - 1
    Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Name = "cqFindRecordString" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = numbers(counter)

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    '''''''''''''''''' Find Label ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("label")
    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).innerText = "IT Lead/Assigned To" Then
            lead = objCollection(i).Value
            'Set objLead = objCollection(i)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Range("B" & (iLastRow - (size - counter - 1))).Value = lead
    Set objElement = ie.document.getElementById("cqFindRecordButton")
    objElement.Click
    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Next counter

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""
MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Note: Website is internal only

Goal: Select Name under "IT Lead/Assigned To" field and paste to Excel

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to preserve the ID or can you just use a regular expression to parse it?

Comment: Only need to parse for the name under IT Lead, I do not need to preserve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the supplied code, tl;dr.

But if you are wanting the scratched out portion you supplied in your HTML snippet, the following may work *(I can't test something that I don't have access to :D)*.

There are many different ways to grab an element, and this method you are grabbing the first instance of the class name `dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer`. Class names are not always a unique value, but due to the somewhat complexity of this class name, I feel somewhat safe that in your case it is.

You could have used one line to `Set yourObj...` but for demonstration purposes I decided to break it up. 1-liner method to **Set** your obj:

```
Set yourObj = doc.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
```

### Code Snippet:

```
Sub getElementFromIE()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    ' ... your above code pulls up webpage ...

    '''''''''''''''''' Find Label ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument, yourObj As Object
    Set doc = ie.document

    ' I assume the class name is unique? If so, just append (0) as I did below
    Set yourObj = doc.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer")(0)
    Set yourObj = yourObj.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
    lead = yourObj.Value

End Sub
```

The reason for the `(1)` on `Set yourObj = yourObj.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)` is because there are 2 `input` tags after your class `dijitReset...`. You are wanting the 2nd instance of this tag, which contains your value; and as you are probably already aware, you are using `Base 0`, meaning the 2nd instance is actually the number 1.